# азбучный вопрос про def test(b=None)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сброс значения аргумента на значение по умолчанию при многократном вызове функции в учебных материалах предлагается в виде

```
def test(b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = []
    b += [1]
    print(b)
```

Этот код с тем же результатом можно записать иначе, и тогда непонятное становится явным:

```
def test(b=[]):
    if b == []:
        b = []
    b += [1]
    print(b)
```

или так

```
def test(b="foo"):
    if b == "foo":
        b = []
```

Похоже, что переменная в аргументах и в теле функции - это что-то разное. Но! Работает это так, будто и в строке, которая полностью в теле функции, `if b == []:  b = []` это разные b

Что я не понимаю? Наверное, вопрос уже был не раз, но я не нашел.

UPD
Я понимаю, что в следующий раз список будет не пустым. Это действительно во всех материалах указано. Но это не объясняет, почему алгоритм заходит внутрь `if b == []:` если список не пустой? Как работает, я понимаю. Я не понимаю, почему.

Comment: `Работает это так, будто и в строке, которая полностью в теле функции, "if b == []: b = []" это разные b` - это не разные b, это разные `[]`, т.е. разные объекты-списки.

Comment: Лень искать дубликаты, но этот вопрос 100 раз обсуждался. Проблема в том, что в питоне списочные дефолтные аргументы вроде `def test(b=[]):` срабатывают только один раз, при последующих обращениях к `test` список `b` будет уже не пустым, если туда что-то положили.

Comment: `Но это не объясняет, почему алгоритм заходит внутрь if b == []: если список не пустой?` - нет, алгоритм **не заходит, если список не пустой**. Запустите пошагово под отладчиком и убедитесь. В целом, ваш способ формально рабочий (пока пользователь не захочет передать внутрь пустой список, чтобы в него добавился элемент), но переусложненный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целом очень интересный пример, запустил его и тоже сначала не понял, а потом понял.

Смотрите, когда вы выполняете фунцию первый раз без аргумента, условие `b == []` срабатывает по очевидной причине. После этого выполняется код `b = []` и это записывает в переменную `b` **уже другой** пустой массив, который никак не связан с тем пустым масивом, который в заголовке функции.

Поэтому когда дальше вы делаете `b += [1]` это меняет тот другой массив. А пустой массив из заголовка функции так и остаётся пустым.

Поэтому при следующем запуске функции с аргументов по умолчанию, в `b` опять записывается пустой массив. И всё тоже самое повторяется по новой.

Answer (score 1):

Такой пример (надеюсь, наглядный):

```
def show(text, x):
    # Выводим текст, значение объекта, и последние 4 цифры адреса объекта в 16-ричном виде
    print(text, x, hex(id(x))[-4:], sep="\t")  


def test(b=[]):
    show("1", b)
    if b == []:
        print("Зашло")
        b = []
    else:
        print("Не зашло")

    show("2", b)
    
    b += [1]
    show("3", b)


print()
print("Вызов 1")
show("default", test.__defaults__[0])
test()

print()
print("Вызов 2")
show("default", test.__defaults__[0])
test([])

print()
print("Вызов 3")
show("default", test.__defaults__[0])
test([1])
```

Пример вывода (части адреса будут при каждом запуске программы разными):

```
Вызов 1
default []      5640
1       []      5640
Зашло
2       []      bc40
3       [1]     bc40

Вызов 2
default []      5640
1       []      bc40
Зашло
2       []      d080
3       [1]     d080

Вызов 3
default []      5640
1       [1]     bc40
Не зашло
2       [1]     bc40
3       [1, 1]  bc40
```

Тут `default` - это тот самый объект-список в параметре `b`, являющийся значением по умолчанию (один и тот же объект на все время работы программы). 1 - что лежит в `b` переменной до `if`, 2 - что после `if`, 3 - после добавления элемента

1. В первом случае ничего не передаем. Сначала (на 1) в `b` значение по умолчанию (адрес  `...5640`), происходит вход в `if` (т.к. это пустой список), значение меняется на другой объект-список, тоже пустой, но с другим адресом (`...bc40`). Тут все по идее должно быть понятно.
2. Во втором случае передаем пустой список. На 1 видим, что это не объект из значения по умолчанию (`5640 != bc40`), но все равно входим в `if`, т.к. это пустой список, на 2 видим, что переданный список заменился на другой (`bc40 != d080`)
3. В третьем случае передаем не пустой список. На 1 очевидно что это разные объекты со списком из default, дальше **не входит** в `if`, т.к. список не пустой, соответственно на 2 этапе видим тот же самый адрес, что и на 1 этапе.

Вот кстати во втором варианте вызова (с пустым списком) будет разница с "каноническим" вариантом (`b=None`):

```
def test1(b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = []
    b += [1]
    print(b)


def test2(b=[]):
    if b == []:
        b = []
    b += [1]
    print(b)


x = []
test1(x)  # Вывод: [1]
print(x)  # Вывод: [1]

x = []
test2(x)  # Вывод: [1]
print(x)  # Вывод: []
```

Т.е. с вашим вариантом переданный снаружи список не изменится, а будет создан новый пустой, никак не связанный с "внешней" переменной `x`.